# Symfony FileType:class does not work when trying to update

Tags: forms, symfony, file-type

Hi everyone I have a question!  How I can solve this problem:

> the form's view data is expected to be  an instance of class
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) resource. You
> can avoid this error by setting the "data_class"  option to null or by
> adding a view transformer that transforms a(n)  resource to an
> instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.

This error happens when I try to update it but it doesn't work with the `FileType::class`

this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace XInteractive\Bundle\LeadsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use XInteractive\Bundle\LeadsBundle\Entity\Document;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null)
            ->add('file', FileType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Document::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show code of your Controller and Entity what related to this Form

And read Official Documentations:

- [How to Upload Files](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)
- [All about Uploading Files in Symfony](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads)

As for me the best way:

```
->add('file', FileType::class, ['mapped' => false])
```

and then write own logic for relation file to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Set `data_class` to null!

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name', null)
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personaly, the issue came from an Chrome Extension.

A colorpicker extension : Geco

I deleted it and restart Chrome and that work.